# como ver un archivo creado en otro metodo

Tags: java, archivo, clase, menu

la idea del programa es crear un menú en el cual la gente por consola elige una opción del 1 al 5
la opción 1 crea el archivo y permite agregarle un dato lo cual funciona perfectamente pero me falla el hecho de la opción 2 la cual envía un nuevo dato al archivo creado anteriormente y lo mismo la opción 3 la cual permite ver el contenido del archivo pero al ejecutarlo la opción 3 me lanza un error el cual no se como solucionar por eso me gustaría ver la posibilidad si es que alguien me puede orientar en el tema, en el fondo mi duda es como utilizar un archivo creado en un método en otro método ya sea para agregarle algún dato, eliminarlo o ver su contenido pero desde otro método

```
public class Practica {
 public String nombrefichero;
  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero1;
        do{
        System.out.println("1-Crear archivo");
        System.out.println("2-Enviar dato");
        System.out.println("3-Ver archivo");
        System.out.println("4-Eliminar archivo");
        System.out.println("5-Salir del progama");
        
         
        System.out.println("Ingresa la opcion que deseas");
        numero1 = scan.nextInt();
        switch(numero1){
            case 1:
                creararchivo("");
                break;
            case 2:
                enviardato("");
                break;
            case 3:
                verarchivo("");
                break;    
            case 4:
                eliminararchivo();
                break;
            case 5:
                salir();
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
        
        }while(numero1>=1 && numero1<=4);
    }
    
    public static void creararchivo(String nombrefichero) throws 
    IOException{
        
        Scanner scan6 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del archivo");
        nombrefichero = scan6.nextLine();
        File fichero = new File (nombrefichero);
        try {
  
        if (fichero.createNewFile())
        System.out.println("El fichero se ha creado correctamente");
        else
        System.out.println("No ha podido ser creado el fichero");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
        String dato2;
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa el primer dato para el archivo");
        dato2 = scan2.nextLine();
        
        
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fichero.getAbsoluteFile(), true));
        bw.write(dato2);
        bw.close();
        
        System.out.println("hola"+fichero);
        }
        public static void enviardato(String fichero) throws IOException{
        String dato6;
        
        Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa el dato que deseas enviarle al archivo");
        dato6 = scan7.nextLine()  
        }
        public static void verarchivo(String fichero) throws IOException{
        String contenido;
        FileReader archiv = new FileReader(fichero);
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(archiv)) {
        while ((contenido = buffer.readLine())!=null){
             System.out.println(contenido);
            }
          }
       }
       public static void eliminararchivo(){
       System.out.println("eliminar");
       }
       public static void salir(){
       System.out.println("El programa se ha cerrado exitosamente");
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer que `creararchivo` retorne la variable `fichero` o la ruta completa de este: `fichero. getAbsolutePath()` guardarlos como una variable y pasarle a cualquier método que necesite acceso a ese archivo

Comment: podria solicitar que se ingrese el nombre del archivo creado en el metodo 2 y 3,o podria declarar la variable `nombreFichero` como `static`

Comment: perfecto, ya he logrado solucionar el problema muchas gracias por su ayuda